# Why does my Java test suite hang the entire system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

When I'm running my test suite for a new java application it hangs, which by itself isn't that unusual considering it's under development. The problem is that that causes the entire system to almost hang. I can move the mouse but a lot of physical mouse movement only causes the mouse pointer on screen to move a centimeter or something.

Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen3.
Linux, Ubuntu gnome 15.10, latest patches.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

It does say Server VM while this is a laptop, is that a possible cause?

I tried `nice -10 mvn clean test` but that didn't help so it does not seem to be CPU-bound, if my understanding of `nice` and process priorities is correct.

Once something crashed and the system went back to normal, the Something-in-the-system-has-crashed-dialog-send-error-report?-dialog showed up and I could use the machine again.

I don't know how to find the cause of this, it's working fine for colleagues running other OS:es. Ideas?

Comment: Try to increase memory for application. Most probably it is swapping to HDD.

Comment: Is that logged somewhere or can I check if that's the case? It's using a lot of memory but I don't have that much more to give. I only have a SSD in this machine.

Comment: I am not sure that it is logged somewhere. But it is usual Java programs behavior. You start the application and set the max amount of RAM memory it can use. However it needs more RAM and then starting to swap everything to HDD. It kills whole system. Try to find this application config file and increase xmx memory.